# Slim Framworrk, function call

Tags: php, slim

for some reason I am not able to call a function, I cant figure it out why.

```
 $app->post( '/login', function () use ($app, $db) { 
     myfunction();
 }
 $app-run();

 function myfunction() {
     echo "hello world";
 }
```

What m I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: @webaba is right, if your function is defined exactly as in the code snippet, it's not in the scope of post(function(...) so you should pass it same as $app and $db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$app-run();`? I think you're missing a `->`.

Comment: True... but thats not the problem. :/

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your function can be reached within the scope of the closure in which you're calling it.

Maybe you want to include it along with $app and $db in the use statement.